# Resulting Object TYPE is different from specified TYPE after http response from Firestore is processed with Behavior Subject in Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My objective is to call tightly typed user profile data from firebase firestore and populate a user profile component template using the angular app-shell to pre-populate the viewport while db data is retrieved and resolved using the angular router resolve() method.

The problem I'm having is that I am unable parse the template data at the end of the process because the shape of the data object is different than what is expected.

I am expecting:

```
{
displayName: 'some name',
photoUrl: 'some url',
uid: 'some user id'
...
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
{name: 'projects/projectName/database/(default)/documents/users/uid',
fields:
      displayName: {stringValue: 'some name'}
      photoUrl: {stringValue: 'some url'}
      uid: {stringValue: 'some user id'}
   ...
}
```

I am using a data model () throughout to populate the db when a user signs up and retrieve data when the user accesses their profile.  I am using a "user service" to get data from the db and populate a getProfileDataWithShell function that will pass on the dataObservable to a route resolver and shell provider before ending up post processed at the user-profile.page component. In the user-profile.page component the data is received as an activated route (from the resolver) and passed through a series of conditions to handle the promise based shell stuff and the observable based db data. Finally the resulting observable is subscribed to and returns the profile object of type UserProfileModel.

Route Resolver and Shell Provider
The route resolver is taking the dataObservable and passing it to the Angular Resolve() method.  I don't think much else is going on here.

The shell provider is using a Behavior Subject which obtains a shellModel from a promise that contains all the pre-populated data and is passed to the component view via a shell cache (app-shell).  The Behavior Subject waits and then receives the dataObservable which is used to populate the rest of the template as the observable completes.  PLEASE NOTE FOR DEV PURPOSES THERE IS A CONFIGURABLE 2 SEC DELAY TO SIMULATE NETWORK DELAY.

If all I had to do was to create another variable and re-parse it in the user-profile component I'd almost be happy at this point.  But since the data is tightly typed using the  type all my options for parsing are strongly related to what is in that model.  HOWEVER, when I observe the resulting object (in Chrome dev tools) it is of the type in the "But I'm getting" section above.  I can see this type throughout the process beginning with the Behavior Subject Object.

This is for and Ionic 4 App using angular 7, Firebase 6 and RXJS 6 sitting on top of Cordova Android.  The Android platform is out of the picture at this phase, meaning this aforementioned stuff does affect the Android build and visa versa. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

------------------ User Profile Model -----------------------

````
```export class UserProfileModel {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoUrl?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  membership?: string;
  job?: string;
  likes?: string;
  followers?: string;
  following?: string;
  about?: string;
  constructor(readonly isShell: boolean) { }
}
```
````

------------------- user.service.ts ------------------------

````
```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private _profileDataWithShellCache: ShellProvider<UserProfileModel>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

public getProfileDataWithShell(): Observable<UserProfileModel> {
    this.userId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    // Use cache if we have it.
    if (!this._profileDataWithShellCache) {
        // Initialize the model specifying that it is a shell model
        const shellModel: UserProfileModel = new UserProfileModel(true);
        const dataObservable = this.http.get<UserProfileModel>(this.baseFsAPIUrl + this.userId + apiKey);
        this._profileDataWithShellCache = new ShellProvider(
            shellModel,
            dataObservable
        );
    }
    return this._profileDataWithShellCache.observable;
```
````

---------------- route resolver ----------------------------------

````
```
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  resolve() {
    // Get the Shell Provider from the service
    const shellProviderObservable = this.userService.getProfileDataWithShell();

    // Resolve with Shell Provider
    const observablePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(shellProviderObservable);
    });
    return observablePromise;
  }
}
```
````

---------------------- shell provider ---------------------------------

````
```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import {first, delay, finalize, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export class ShellProvider<T> {
  private _observable: Observable<T>;
  private _subject: BehaviorSubject<T>;
  private networkDelay = (environment && environment.shell && environment.shell.networkDelay) ? environment.shell.networkDelay : 0;
  // To debug shell styles, change configuration in the environment.ts file
  private debugMode = (environment && environment.shell && environment.shell.debug) ? environment.shell.debug : false;

  constructor(shellModel: T, dataObservable: Observable<T>) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    const shellClassName = (shellModel && shellModel.constructor && shellModel.constructor.name) ? shellModel.constructor.name : 'No Class Name';

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.time('[' + shellClassName + '] ShellProvider roundtrip - first one on BS shellModel');
    // Set the shell model as the initial value
    this._subject = new BehaviorSubject<T>(shellModel);

      dataObservable.pipe(
          take(1), // Prevent the need to unsubscribe because .first() completes the observable
          // finalize(() => console.log('dataObservable COMPLETED'))
      );

    const delayObservable = of(true).pipe(
      delay(this.networkDelay),
      // finalize(() => console.log('delayObservable COMPLETED'))
    );

    // Put both delay and data Observables in a forkJoin so they execute in parallel so that
    // the delay caused (on purpose) by the delayObservable doesn't get added to the time the dataObservable takes to complete
    const forkedObservables = forkJoin(
      delayObservable,
      dataObservable
    )
    .pipe(
      // finalize(() => console.log('forkedObservables COMPLETED'))
    )
    .subscribe(([delayValue, dataValue]: [boolean, T]) => {
      if (!this.debugMode) {
        this._subject.next(dataValue);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.timeEnd('[' + shellClassName + '] ShellProvider roundtrip');
      }
    });

    this._observable = this._subject.asObservable();
  }

  public get observable(): Observable<T> {
    return this._observable;
  }
}
```
````

---------------------------- user-profile.page component --------------------

````
```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { UserProfileModel } from './user-profile.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './styles/user-profile.page.scss',
    './styles/user-profile.shell.scss',
    './styles/user-profile.ios.scss',
    './styles/user-profile.md.scss'
  ],
})
export class UserProfilePage implements OnInit {
  profile: UserProfileModel;

  @HostBinding('class.is-shell') get isShell() {
    return (this.profile && this.profile.isShell) ? true : false;
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.route && this.route.data) {
      // We resolved a promise for the data Observable
      const promiseObservable = this.route.data;
      console.log('Route Resolve Observable => promiseObservable: ', promiseObservable);

      if (promiseObservable) {
        promiseObservable.subscribe(promiseValue => {
          const dataObservable = promiseValue['data'];
          console.log('Subscribe to promiseObservable => dataObservable: ', dataObservable);

          if (dataObservable) {
            dataObservable.subscribe(observableValue => {
              const pageData: UserProfileModel = observableValue;
              // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
              console.log('Subscribe to dataObservable (can emmit multiple values) => PageData (' + ((pageData && pageData.isShell) ? 'SHELL' : 'REAL') + '): ', pageData);
              // As we are implementing an App Shell architecture, pageData will be firstly an empty shell model,
              // and the real remote data once it gets fetched
              if (pageData) {
                this.profile = pageData;
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.warn('No dataObservable coming from Route Resolver promiseObservable');
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.warn('No promiseObservable coming from Route Resolver data');
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('No data coming from Route Resolver');
    }
  }
}

```
````

-------------------- user-profile.page template ----------------------------

````
```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="user-profile-content">
  <ion-row class="user-details-section">
    <ion-col class="user-image-wrapper">
      <app-aspect-ratio [ratio]="{w: 1, h: 1}">
        <app-image-shell class="user-image" animation="spinner" [src]="profile.photoUrl"></app-image-shell>
      </app-aspect-ratio>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="user-info-wrapper">
      <ion-row class="user-data-row">
        <ion-col size="9">
          <h3 class="user-name">
            <app-text-shell [data]="profile.displayName"></app-text-shell>
          </h3>
          <h5 class="user-title">
            <app-text-shell [data]="profile.job"></app-text-shell>
          </h5>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="membership-col">
          <span class="user-membership">
            <app-text-shell [data]="profile.membership"></app-text-shell>
          </span>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="actions-row">
        <ion-col class="main-actions">
          <ion-button class="call-to-action-btn" size="small" color="primary">Follow</ion-button>
          <ion-button class="call-to-action-btn" size="small" color="medium">Message</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="secondary-actions">
          <ion-button class="more-btn" size="small" fill="clear" color="medium">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="more"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="user-stats-section">
    <ion-col class="user-stats-wrapper" size="4">
      <span class="stat-value">
        <app-text-shell [data]="profile.likes"></app-text-shell>
      </span>
      <span class="stat-name">Likes</span>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="user-stats-wrapper" size="4">
      <span class="stat-value">
        <app-text-shell [data]="profile.followers"></app-text-shell>
      </span>
      <span class="stat-name">Followers</span>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="user-stats-wrapper" size="4">
      <span class="stat-value">
        <app-text-shell [data]="profile.following"></app-text-shell>
      </span>
      <span class="stat-name">Following</span>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <div class="user-about-section">
    <h3 class="details-section-title">About</h3>
    <p class="user-description">
      <app-text-shell animation="bouncing" lines="4" [data]="profile.about"></app-text-shell>
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```








```

I am expecting:

{
displayName: 'some name',
photoUrl: 'some url',
uid: 'some user id'
...
}

But I'm getting: 

{name: 'projects/projectName/database/(default)/documents/users/uid',
fields:
      displayName: {stringValue: 'some name'}
      photoUrl: {stringValue: 'some url'}
      uid: {stringValue: 'some user id'}
   ...
}
```
````

I am not getting any error messages which is weird.  Again if anyone can help me to understand:

1. Why I'm not ending up with the expected object format in the user-profile.page component, thus the template?
2. Why I cannot access the fields: data value pairs in the "But I'm getting:" format?

I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After too many hours trying to resolve this I finally did an AngularFire2 update and made a few other changes to get it working.   Hopefully this will help anyone who has this issue:

1. First, I needed to upgrade to AngularFire ^5.2.1
2. In the user.service I made these changes:

```
  public getListingDataSource(): Observable<Array<UserProfileModel>> {
    return this.afs.collection<UserProfileModel>('users').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  }`

3. In the route.resolver 

`export class FirebaseListingResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  resolve() {
    const dataSource: Observable<Array<UserProfileModel>> = this.userService.getListingDataSource();

    const dataStore: DataStore<Array<UserProfileModel>> = this.userService.getListingStore(dataSource);

    return dataStore;
  }
}`

4. Finally in the user profile component

`
listing: Array<UserProfileModel>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe((resolvedRouteData) => {
      const listingDataStore = resolvedRouteData['data'];

      listingDataStore.state.subscribe(
        (state) => {
          this.listing = state;
        },
        (error) => {}
      );
})
`
```